# deployment without physical access to device

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

I'm wondering if there is a way to show my App to customer before sending it to store.

(and if there is a way to unlock phone to deploy the app into remotely - but officially, nothing illegal).

I need to show "work in progress" to customer who can't visit me and I can't visit him. I have Develoepr Acc and he has some Windows Device he can test it on, but I don't know how to get the app to him before I submit it to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx

You can send the `XAP` of your project to your customer and he can deploy it on a developer unlocked device using the `XAP Deployment Tool` of `Microsoft SDK`. You can find your `XAP` in the `Bin/Release` folder of your project. Make sure you deploy your project on `Release` before you send it to your customer or upload on the store. Check this link you'll find out how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that is probably more applicable in many situations is to release a beta version of your app to the store. You'll be able to specify who can install it and you're required to email them a link to the app. The app is not available to the general public and will only work for 90 days from the time you publish it.

This method is more work for you but it lets you give the app to potentially thousands of users and doesn't require that they have a developer/unlocked device.

See [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article for a how-to on releasing a beta application.